How to call logistic regression model through flask API?
Created a logistic regression model which works fine, predicting correct values so far when running locally (through PyCharm).
Trying to call model through flask API and thus created a pickle file.
Not sure how do I call classifier.predict method in API which is line #7 in below code? as I do not have an instance available (what am I missing? or doing something wrong ?)
API code

from flask import Flask, request, render_template, jsonify
import pickle

app = Flask(__name__)

-- Load pickle file
with open('sc.pkl', 'rb') as file:
    model = pickle.load(file) 

@app.route("/test", methods=["GET"])
def test():
    trans = model.transform([[1, 0, 12, 30]])

-- Idea is to test through hard coded values first and later on make it parameterized.
This is where I'm struggling as I do not have the instance of classifier to call predict method ( Line # 7 in below code)
here is the actual code that I ran successfully from pycharm(.py file)-
1. reading CSV,
   assign values to x,y,
   running train_test_split function
2. sc = StandardScaler()
3. x_train = sc.fit_transform(x_train)
4. x_test = sc.transform(x_test)

5. classifier = LogisticRegression(random_state=0)
6. classifier.fit(x_train,y_train)

7. print(classifier.predict(sc.transform([[1, 0, 12,30]]))) -- Prediction
8. pickle.dump(sc, open('sc.pkl','wb')) -- Pickle file is getting created here

